# Joomla: how to show the modified date of your articles in google searches?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'd like that my articles show up the modified date in Google searches.
Currently my Joomla 3 site, when modified date's output is enabled, shows the following tag:

```
<time datetime="2019-01-07T07:48:41+00:00" itemprop="dateModified">
```

However, I can see that it doesn't work to hint Google about the modified date.
Is there a plugin/hack to let the date show in Google searches ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is still the case or even applies to your situation but Google may ignore structured data in favour of visible content. For details see: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/78929

You could try the free [Google Structured Data Markup](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/google-structured-data-markup) extension from Tassos Marinos to see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have tested with:

- date created
- last update / modified and published

The trick that Google use is simple.
He take the snippet that is visible to the user.
This is why sometime it displayed 03.04.2018 or 3. April 2018.
Here is a link to my site:. 
https://www.usa-reisetipps.net/einreise-usa/esta-visum
See the source code by the author. Google use the visible text between the Meta's

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers! I have changed the sitemap plugin for my site and now dates are showing up in the search. Here is the plugin I have used: https://www.aimy-extensions.com/joomla/sitemap.html